# Change browser's URL after authorization redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, angular-ui-router, appauth

I am performing an authorization process where my application receives the `code` and `state` that will be used to exchange for access/refresh tokens. This is coming via a redirect from an identity provider. After processing and obtaining the token, I then do

```
$state.go('main', {
  inherit: false
});
```

which continues the application.

In doing so, my browser's url looks like something like this:

```
https://www.darkside.com/?code=f9c84c3cc47944915a10aa2723f4a31893e59c984f1f703c2bf49eb157fe6dca&state=4QJx86U9I5#/Main
```

How do I change the url on the browser to without reloading into something like below? Is it even possible? I tried doing `window.location.pushState` but it does not alter the browser's url.

```
https://www.darkside.com/#/Main
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$location.search({}); // add this
$state.go('main', {
   inherit: false
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunately, it did not work. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the queryParams not being at the end of the url.

Comment: Oh didn’t see that before. Yeah those are in the wrong spot for sure

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.